# Some computation with a power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

This is an old qualifying exam problem that has me stumped.

Suppose  $$F(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$$  converges in some neighborhood of the origin. I want to compute  $$\sup\left\{\delta>0 : \text{ there exists } \epsilon>0 \text{ such that } \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\big|F(x)\big|^{-\delta}dx<\infty \right\}$$ The integrals are to be interpreted as improper Riemann integrals if $F(0)=0$.

I'd greatly appreciate any hints or suggestions on how to get started with this.

Comment: There exists $\epsilon>0$ so that... what?

Comment: Haha oops! It would've helped to have more quantifiers. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $F(0)\ne0$ case is easy.

When $F(0)=0$, the point is that near zero the term with the lowest degree will dominate. So let $k=\min\{n:\ a_n\ne0\}$ (i.e. $k$ is the multiplicity of $0$ as a root of $F$). Then $F^{(k)}(0) =a_k\ne0$. By writing the remainder of the Taylor polynomial we have
$$
F(x)=\frac1{k!}\,F^{(k)}(\xi)\,x^k
$$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$. By choosing $\epsilon$ small enough,  we deduce from the continuity of $F^{(k)}$ that there exist positive constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ with
$$
k_1\,|x|^k\leq|F(x)|\leq k_2\,|x|^k, \ \ \ x\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon).
$$

For the improper integral 
$$
\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon|x^k|^{-\delta}\,dx
$$
to be finite, we need $k\delta<1$, or $\delta<1/k$. As
$$
k_2^{-\delta}\int_{\epsilon}^\epsilon|x^k|^{-\delta}\,dx\leq\int_{\epsilon}^\epsilon|F(x)|^{-\delta}\,dx\leq k_1^{-\delta}\int_{\epsilon}^\epsilon|x^k|^{-\delta}\,dx,
$$
the integral in the middle will be finite precisely when $\delta<1/k$. So the desired supremum is $1/k$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! One question: shouldn't the remainder of our Taylor polynomial be $F^{(k)}(\xi)x^k/k!$ rather than what you have written (without the factorial)?

Comment: Yes, of course. Corrected now.

Comment: Great. In the "easy" case, the supremum is infinite, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. $\ $

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again!